# Radio button not checked breaks page but works if checked

Tags: coldfusion

I have a simple form that I'm trying to pass data to which on the action page has an email that sends the data that I put into the form.

On my form page. I have a text field and two radio buttons.

My text field works if I don't put data into it. However, on my radio buttons the page works if I check it but doesnt work if I don't check it at all which results in my page breaking I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong? I want the page to process the default to "no" if I didn't check either radio buttons. Do I have to validate or something?

Here is my code.

```
<cfparam name="form.firstName" default="">
<cfparam name = "form.optradio1" default="no">

<form action="test.cfm" method="post">
  <label for="firstName"></label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio1" Value="Male" <cfif form.optradio1 eq "Yes">checked</cfif>>
</form>
```

Comment: I only see one radio button.  In any event, the simplest solution is to pre-check the no button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how radio and checkbox inputs work in HTML. If they are not checked, they are not submitted on the form submit.

To determine if the radio input was checked, you can use
`structKeyExists(form, <name of the input, as string>)` as in
`structKeyExists(form, "optradio1")`.

```
<cfparam name="form.firstName" default="">

<form action="test.cfm" method="post">
  <label for="firstName"></label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio1" Value="Male" <cfif structKeyExists(form, "optradio1")>checked</cfif>>
</form>
```

Assuming you have two radio inputs:

```
<cfparam name="form.firstName" default="">

<form action="test.cfm" method="post">
  <label for="firstName"></label>
  <input type="text" name="firstName">
  <input type="radio" name="optradio1" Value="Male" <cfif structKeyExists(form, "optradio1") and form.optradio1 eq "Male">checked</cfif>>
  <input type="radio" name="optradio1" Value="Female" <cfif structKeyExists(form, "optradio1") and form.optradio1 eq "Female">checked</cfif>>
</form>
```

Your initial code doesn't work because:

- if checked, `form.optradio1` was equal to `Male`
- if not checked, `form.optradio1` was defaulted to `no` because of
  `<cfparam name = "form.optradio1" default="no">`

Comment: Okay thanks i'll try it and see if it works appreciate the help!

Comment: This works but what if I wanted to NOT check any of the radio buttons and for the page to process? Cause basically what I'm trying to do is if Male checkbox was checked, return male if female was checked, return female, however if neither was checked and I hit submit, return None or no.

Comment: Use a select box

Comment: @Curious13 `<cfif not structKeyExists(form, "optradio1")>nothing was selected</cfif>`

Comment: I see. Thank you!